# How to parse data by array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, parsing

I am developing an android application were I want to parse data through an array to URL API.

Taking an example, there are 5 TextBox and I enter some information in it. Then all the values entered in textView should parse in an array format to That API URL.

Please help!!

Comment: you want to send that array to server actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send that array to server via an api, then you should send data in JSONArray like this

```
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray();    
jArray.put(yourTextViewText1);
jArray.put(yourTextViewText2);
jArray.put(yourTextViewText3);
jArray.put(yourTextViewText4);
jArray.put(yourTextViewText5);
```

and you can send that to server like that

```
params.put("key",jArray.toString());
```

Moreover, It is easy for you web developer to parse this JSONArray.

Comment: Thanks veryy much let me try I will be back

Answer (score 2):

This is what i did, note that this is just an example.

```
final Map<String,String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   postParam.put("child_id[" + i + "]", i+"");
```

You will get :

`child_id[0]` with value `0`
`child_id[1]` with value `i`
And goes on.

UPDATE

In your case, you might want to do something like :

postParam.put("child_id[" + i + "]", myEditText.getText.toString());

for each of your `edittext`.

Feel free to comment if you dont understand my answer or if i miss-understood you.

Answer (score 1):

I hope i am understanding you correctly, you want to put 5 TextBox's entered text into one Array and then send this Array to API.

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> textViewTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
// Put all EditText's text to array
// Do this for each EditText
textViewTexts.add(someEditText.getText());
```

You can then use textViewTexts.toString() and send this to API.

EDIT:
you can parse textViewTexts like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < textViewTexts.size(); i++) {
    String text = textViewTexts.get(i);
    // Do something with text..
}
```

EDIT2:
you can parse textViewTexts like this:

```
JSONArray jArray=new JSONArray();    
for (int i = 0; i < textViewTexts.size(); i++) {
    String text = textViewTexts.get(i);
    jArray.put(text);
}
// Send JSONArray to API
jArray.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks! can you please tell me after adding the value all textbox in TextViewTexts How can I parse it